# jQuery not loading: Failed to load resource: The request timed out

Tags: jquery, django, bootstrap-4

I'm developing an Django Webapp and I've recently been having issues with jQuery.  Within my Webapp on Safari web browser, the main web page stalls and never loads jQuery source code resource from the CDN. Keep receiving this error:

> Failed to load resource: The request timed out.

I have tried my app on other computers within my home network, but it does not work there either. Tested it at my work and everything is flawless. I also maintain a website that is utilizing jQuery and it's having the same issue. Some solutions I've attempted: Clearing the browser histories and cookies. I also used some CLI tools like ping and traceroute to determine if the problem is somehow network related or the resource being blocked.  Is it possible jQuery is being blocked?

```
<body>

<!-- Content is here ... -->

  {% load static %}
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.rtlcss.com/bootstrap/v4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a9xOd0rz8w0J8zqj1qJic7GPFfyMfoiuDjC9rqXlVOcGO/dmRqzMn34gZYDTel8k"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="{% static 'js/app.js' %}"></script>

</body>
```

[JS console on Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dc7eU.png)

Comment: Show console error

Comment: Ok, I'll try that.

Comment: Yes, it works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using Google CDN instead.?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It works! I thought of changing the CDN link. Thanks!

Comment: I have had problems with the jquery CDN in the past. If that worked please feel free to accept the answer.